# "Problems"-tab in Android Studio Hedgehog only showing error in current file (not whole project)

Tags: android-studio

After switching to Android Studio Hedgehog I quickly realized that the "Problems"-tab is now only showing the error on the currently opened File. It used to show errors in all files automatically (without needing to manually analyze).
[Screenshot of "Problem"-tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rJvR.png)

I am using

- Flutter/Dart
- Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 2 (built Jan 19, 2024)
- Windows 11

ChatGPT, Copilot & Google have not been able to help.